# Here Maps - download maps according to route?

Tags: maps, here

I frequently drive long distances in central Europe. Here Maps in offline mode works good enough for this but one thing is very annoying when I plan my routes: the big countries (Germany, France, UK, Italy, Spain) are divided into regions and every time I have to figure out which regions I will drive through so I can download the correct maps. Is there a way to make my phone, based on the suggested route, select the minimal amount of maps that is needed and download them automatically?

Comment: Here maps are divided based on provinces or states, in western countries and india too. But i don't know about Europe.

Comment: What? What has this comment to do with my question?

Answer (score 1):

Well the only way you can use the offline feature of the here maps is by manually selecting and downloading the regions through which you will be travelling. <strike>But i have the perfect solution for your problem why not use HERE DRIVE it has the capability of downloading the minimal map data so that you can travel through different regions without having to download the entire map , it has turn by turn voice navigation too</strike>.

```
EDIT:check the comments !
```

Hope this helped !

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, of course I use Here Drive for the actual guidance. How do I make Here Drive download only the required regions and countries for trip? I haven't found any such option.

Comment: well i tried and tried, i guess you have to manually download the regions. Try to download the entire Europe map onto your sd card if its possible.

Comment: there will be drawbacks if the map is downloaded in the minimal data like no traffic update , no detours , if you take a wrong turn it cannot reroute you back ... etc.  I guess thats why there is no such feature available

Comment: Minimal = minimal amount of regions/countries. That is, not just the route and 100 meters around it. E.g., Bavaria is rather big.

Comment: send them a feature request through their support email they might add it ! Many developers take it seriously